# What does 'granularity' affect in druid's select query?

Tags: druid

As it says on [druid doc](http://druid.io/docs/0.12.1/querying/select-query.html), Select queries return raw Druid rows, so what does granularity mean in select query? In my opinion, select doesn't need this argument since it returns raw rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes granularity doesn't have much to do in case of select query returning raw data. 
Though its not mandatory field and defaults to ALL.